# How can I get the methods of a class that return void?

Tags: c#, void, gettype, getproperties

I need to get the methods with return-type void, something similar to this:

[Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e687hf0d(v=vs.110).aspx).

[Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx).

How can i do a similar thing which tells me the methods whose return-type is void?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to get *methods whose return type is void?*

Comment: And what do you mean by "the voids of a *script*?"

Comment: Answer to 1 and 2. ya i mean all method return void,
public void voidA (){}
public void voidB (){}
public void voidC (){}
i want a list as following
voidA, voidB, voidC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want to call Type.GetMethods, which returns information about all methods, and then look for results where methodInfo.ReturnType == typeof(void).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ya exactly that, awesome, and another question how can i call this method after by using this?
  public void callVoid (params object[] obj) {
   target.GetType ().GetMethods (...).call (obj);
  }

Comment: Sorry, i am new to coding, just from a couple of months, and i don't know how to express what i want in code language, sorry.